# after drawing on pdf canvas when i save,it is saving without drawings,

Tags: pdf, react-pdf

this is the Brush.tsx file

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
import { PDFDocument, rgb, PDFPage } from 'pdf-lib';
import { Spinner } from '../../Icons/icons';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
  'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js',
  import.meta.url
).toString();

interface BrushProps {
  pdfUrl: string;
}

const Brush: React.FC<BrushProps> = ({ pdfUrl }) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const [pdfNumPages, setPdfNumPages] = useState<number>(0);
  const [pdfPageWidth, setPdfPageWidth] = useState<number>(0);
  const [pdfPageHeight, setPdfPageHeight] = useState<number>(0);
  const [isPaintEnabled, setPaintEnabled] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [tempPageArray, setTempPageArray] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [brushSize, setBrushSize] = useState<number>(5);
  let isDrawing = false;
  let lastX = 0;
  let lastY = 0;

  const togglePaint = () => {
    setPaintEnabled(!isPaintEnabled);
  };

  // Function to update the brush size
  const handleBrushSizeChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const newSize = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    setBrushSize(newSize);
  };

  const startDrawing = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>) => {
    if (!isPaintEnabled) return;
    isDrawing = true;
    [lastX, lastY] = [e.nativeEvent.offsetX, e.nativeEvent.offsetY];
  };

  const draw = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>) => {
    try {
      if (!isDrawing || !isPaintEnabled) return;
      const ctx = (e.target as any)?.getContext('2d');

      if (ctx) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.lineWidth = brushSize;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(e.nativeEvent.offsetX, e.nativeEvent.offsetY);
        ctx.stroke();

        [lastX, lastY] = [e.nativeEvent.offsetX, e.nativeEvent.offsetY];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, 'error');
    }
  };

  const endDrawing = () => {
    isDrawing = false;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;

    if (canvas) {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // Set initial dimensions for the overlay canvas
      canvas.width = pdfPageWidth;
      canvas.height = pdfPageHeight;

      // Clear the overlay canvas initially
      if (ctx) ctx.clearRect(0, 0, pdfPageWidth, pdfPageHeight);
    }
  }, [pdfPageWidth, pdfPageHeight]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTempPageArray(Array.from({ length: pdfNumPages }, (_, i) => i + 1));
  }, [pdfNumPages]);

  const saveEditedPdf = async () => {
    try {
      const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(pdfUrl).then((res) =>
        res.arrayBuffer()
      );
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);

      for (let i = 0; i < pdfNumPages; i++) {
        console.log(canvasRef, 'canvasRef');
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        if (!canvas) continue;

        const overlayCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (!overlayCtx) continue;

        const overlayUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); // Get the data URL of the canvas
        const overlayImage = await pdfDoc.embedPng(overlayUrl); // Embed the canvas as an image in the PDF

        const [copiedPage] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfDoc, [i]); // <-- Pass an array with the page index to copyPages
        copiedPage.drawImage(overlayImage, {
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: pdfPageWidth,
          height: pdfPageHeight,
        });

        pdfDoc.removePage(i); // Remove the old page with no overlay
        pdfDoc.insertPage(i, copiedPage); // Insert the updated page with overlay
      }

      const editedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
      const editedPdfBlob = new Blob([editedPdfBytes], {
        type: 'application/pdf',
      });
      const editedPdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(editedPdfBlob);
      console.log('Edited PDF URL:', editedPdfUrl);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = editedPdfUrl;
      a.download = 'edited-pdf.pdf';
      a.click();

      // Now you can send the editedPdfUrl to the backend for further processing
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error while saving edited PDF:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ overflowY: 'scroll', height: '500px' }}>
        <Document
          file={pdfUrl}
          loading={<Spinner />}
          onLoadSuccess={({ numPages }) => setPdfNumPages(numPages)}
        >
          {tempPageArray.map((page: number) => (
            <div key={page}>
              <Page
                pageNumber={page}
                width={600}
                renderTextLayer={false}
                onMouseDown={startDrawing}
                onMouseMove={draw}
                onMouseUp={endDrawing}
                onMouseOut={endDrawing}
                renderAnnotationLayer={false}
              />
              {'page : ' + page}
            </div>
          ))}
        </Document>
      </div>
      <button className="mx-1" onClick={saveEditedPdf}>
        Save
      </button>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="1"
        max="50"
        value={brushSize}
        onChange={handleBrushSizeChange}
      />
      <span>Brush Size: {brushSize}</span>

      <button onClick={togglePaint}>
        {isPaintEnabled ? 'Disable Paint' : 'Enable Paint'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Brush;
```

int this canvasRef is coming null, i think that, is why is able to embed the canvas drawings in the pdf, in this i am using react-pdf library to view the pdf and using canvas to draw onto the pdf, when i am trying to save the pdf it is saving without the drawings. so in the saveEditedPdf i am using pdf-lib library to embed the canvas drawings into the pdf, but it is still not working.